# Compare two dataframe and look for specific value by group ID

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. For each ID i need to look for the label TRUE, then take corresponding id and date and look for them in the second dataframe, take the value e write it in the first dataframe. Could you please help?

first df

| ID | DAY | LABEL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 01/26/2020 | TRUE |
| AA | 01/27/2020 | FALSE |
| BB | 01/28/2020 | TRUE |
| BB | 01/29/2020 | FALSE |
| BB | 01/30/2020 | FALSE |

second df

| ID | DAY | VAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 01/26/2020 | 50 |
| AA | 01/27/2020 | 60 |
| BB | 01/28/2020 | 200 |

final output

| ID | DAY | LABEL | VAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 01/26/2020 | TRUE | 50 |
| AA | 01/27/2020 | FALSE |  |
| BB | 01/28/2020 | TRUE | 200 |
| BB | 01/29/2020 | FALSE |  |
| BB | 01/30/2020 | FALSE |  |

Comment: Is the 100 VAL for BB correct in output?

Comment: sorry it was wrong, i edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for a "left join", this can be done by merging them. Simply add the column 'LABEL' to the second database:

```
df1.merge(df2.assign(LABEL=True), how='left', on=['ID', 'DAY', 'LABEL'])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
df1['DAY'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.DAY)
df2['DAY'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.DAY)

df = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='DAY', by='ID')
df['VAL']=df.VAL.mask(~df['LABEL']) ## Edited after learning
```

**Output**

```
    ID  DAY         LABEL   VAL
0   AA  2020-01-26  True    50.0
1   AA  2020-01-27  False   NaN
2   BB  2020-01-28  True    200.0
3   BB  2020-01-29  False   NaN
4   BB  2020-01-30  False   NaN
```

**Explanation**

1. Considering first data frame as df1 and second one as df2.
2. Typecasting DAY column of each df to Timestamp type.
3. Merging both DFs on Day column with as of on 'ID'
4. If VAL column has False in output then replacing those values with np.NAN.

This would work on exact Date Match as well as asof date match.